# Exercise package : how to reference a problem environment in answers?

Tags: exercises

Let us consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}

%Environnement exercice
\newenvironment{exo}[1][\unskip]{%
\begin{Exercise}[title={#1}]}
{\end{Exercise}}

%Problème
\newcounter{prob}
\newenvironment{prob}[1][\unskip]{%
\begin{Exercise}[name={Problème}, counter={prob}, title={#1}]} {\end{Exercise}}

\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Solution}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\medskip\centerline{\textbf{ Answer (\ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB)}\smallskip}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

ABCDE

\begin{exo}
ABCDE   
\end{exo}

\begin{Answer}
A
\end{Answer}

\begin{prob}
ABC
\end{prob}
\begin{Answer}
A
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

Output :

[image]

Is it possible to change the line **Answer (Exercise 1)** in **Answer (Problem 1)** automatically in terms of the exercise type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exercise` package stores custom names, if provided, in the internal macro `\@ExerciseName`. This is listed in page 17 of the manual:

```
\define@key{PPExercise}{name}%
{\global\@ExeReNametrue\gdef\@ExerciseName{#1}}
```

You can use this macro in the definition of the answer header. Note that because it is an internal macro (it contains `@`) you need to surround the use of the macro with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

When no custom name is provided (such as in the `exo` environment in the example) then this macro is either undefined (if no custom names have been used so far) or empty. In that case you should use the original `\ExerciseName`. In the code below the macro `\ifdefempty` from the `etoolbox` package is used to test which of the two macros should be used.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}

%Environnement exercice
\newenvironment{exo}[1][\unskip]{%
\begin{Exercise}[title={#1}]}
{\end{Exercise}}

%Problème
\newcounter{prob}
\newenvironment{prob}[1][\unskip]{%
\begin{Exercise}[name={Problème}, counter={prob}, title={#1}]} {\end{Exercise}}

\makeatletter
\def\myExerciseName{\ifdefempty{\@ExerciseName}{\ExerciseName}{\@ExerciseName}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Solution}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\medskip\centerline{\textbf{ Answer (\myExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB)}\smallskip}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

ABCDE

\begin{exo}
ABCDE   
\end{exo}

\begin{Answer}
A
\end{Answer}

\begin{prob}
ABC
\end{prob}
\begin{Answer}
A
\end{Answer}

\begin{exo}
XYZ   
\end{exo}

\begin{Answer}
QWE
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]